# Regular Expression to match rows with less char count

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to mach some rows in a file

Sample:

```
"asdasdasd,1212312,123123
asdadsas",234234,234234
"asddasd",325235,25235423
"aasd aasd,",235345354,534534
```

Now I want to match row 1 & 2 because there is only one `"` sign.

I tried a lot of regexp but cant find the right one...

tried stuf like

```
["]{1,}
["]{2,}
*?["]{2,}
```

and way more... but all seams to be wrong....

It should work in notepad++

any ideas how to match them?

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of fields? Always 3, comma-separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this do the trick:

```
.*".*".*
```

This should be reverse:

```
^(?!(.*".*".*))
```

Comment: matches only 1 row

Comment: try `/.*".*".*/gm`

Comment: how to set this in notepad++ ?

Comment: ah, i had a wrong option set... there are . find \r and \n as well. Is it possible to turn the statement around. like negate it?

Comment: no it doesnt ^^ but Its ok, i can turn around the marks in npp